# PHP array to iOS NSArray

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, arrays, json

Okay, so I have an array in PHP. The one I want in Obj-C is $jsonFilteredUniqueColumns. I know that I can convert to JSON and parse to Obj-C, but whenever I do that, I always get a null value.

PHP:

```
//Let's create some variables
        $username = $_GET['username'];

        //Let's get the userID
        $userIDQuery = sprintf("SELECT ID FROM user_info WHERE Username = '$username';");
        $userIDResult = mysqli_query($connect, $userIDQuery);
        $userID_row = mysqli_fetch_array($userIDResult);
        $ID = $userID_row['ID'];

        //Let's search the tables for that user's existence
        $existenceTablesQuery = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('$username') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='u830212761_users';");
        $existenceTablesResult = mysqli_query($connect, $existenceTablesQuery);

        if ($existenceTablesResult === FALSE) {
            die(mysqli_error($connect));
        }

        $tables = array();
        while ($existenceTablesRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($existenceTablesResult)) {
            array_push($tables, $existenceTablesRow['TABLE_NAME']);
        }

        //Let's get the other person name

        $tablesCount = count($tables);
        $emptyColumn = array();
        $messages = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $tablesCount; $i++) {

            $searchQuery = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `%s`;",$tables[$i]);
            $searchResult = mysqli_query($connect, $searchQuery);

            if ($searchResult === FALSE) {
                die(mysqli_error($connect));
            }

            while ($searchRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {
                foreach($searchRow as $key => $val) {
                    if (empty($val) || is_null($val)) {
                        array_push($emptyColumn, $key);
                    }
                }
                $messages[] = array($searchRow['sender'], $searchRow['message']);
            }
        }

        //Let's get the other users
        $filteredColumns = array_diff($emptyColumn, array($username));
        $filteredUniqueColumns = array_unique($filteredColumns);
        $jsonFilteredUniqueColumns = json_encode($filteredUniqueColumns);
        return $jsonFilteredUniqueColumns;
```

And, Obj-C:

```
//Get the URL
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ezgamexchange.tk/inbox.php?username=%@",user];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//Create the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
int jsonCount = [json count];
NSLog(@"%i",jsonCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the returned value from your php script?

If you get an `array`, so you should store it within a `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`).

By the way, `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, did you alloc/init your object?

```
NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

or:

```
NSArray *json = [[NSArray alloc] init];
...
```